# Does SubmissionError works with FieldArray fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

If so, how to pass the field name properly to make it display the error within the component?

The way I did it below doesn't work:

```
<FieldArray name='myFieldArray' component={renderArrayField} />

function onSubmit(values) {

    values.myFieldArray.forEach((myField, index) => {

        if (!myField.someText) {

            const errorObj = {}
            const myFieldName = "myFieldArray[" + index + "].someText"

            errorObj[myFieldName] = 'Field required!'
            throw new SubmissionError(errorObj)
        }
    })

    // save the form
}
```

I have also tried with:

```
const myFieldName = "myFieldArray[" + index + "].someText._error"
```

and

```
const myFieldName = "myFieldArray[" + index + "]['someText']"
```

and

```
const myFieldName = "myFieldArray[" + index + "]['someText']['_error']"
```

but no deal as well...

Comment: I've tried to encapsulate the array index within single quotes (strings) but that didn't do it either.

Comment: In the end my case seems to be related to not passing the full redux form props to the child functional component that I was rendering as the form fields. Ensure to pass the full props or props.error when trying to render errors on your functional component.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use deep object to display error for nested fields. Like this:

```
const errorObj = {
  myFieldArray: { 
    [index]: { 
      someText: 'Field required!' 
    } 
  }
};

throw new SubmissionError(errorObj);
```